# How to fix missing script : serve?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, npm-scripts

When I run npm run serve in terminal, I got error "missing script : serve"
and here my package.json file :

```
{

  "name": "internship",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },

  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're likely in the wrong directory

Comment: `cd` to whichever directory your `package.json` is in then do `npm run serve`

Comment: yup, I tried npm run serve in terminal and shows errors : npm ERR! missing script: serve , how to fix that? @Adam Azad

Comment: can you explain? sorry I didn't get it @Daniel_Knights

Comment: For example, if your Vue app is in a directory named `client`, open the command line, `cd client`, `npm run serve`

Comment: I had tried and shows -bash: cd: signin: No such file or directory @Daniel_Knights

Comment: You'd have to `cd signup` from the root of the project if `signup` is in the root

Comment: You have to `cd` from the parent directory, you can't just `cd` from anywhere